# Numpy generate random whole number

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to generate a whole number/integer? I am attempting to find a way to generate a random number that is either a 0 or 1 or 2.... and Nothing in between. If I use:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(5):
    action = np.random.uniform(0,2,1)#take random action between 0 1 or 2
    print(action)
```

Returns:

```
[0.18429578]
[1.19763353]
[1.93240698]
[1.44706511]
[0.31182739]
```

[numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint) seems like it would work but it will return an array. Would some sort of function be the best method to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use numpy?  There are [a few methods in `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers) that would do what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not get a one-element array and select its 0th element?

Comment: why will it return an array? it is perfectly capable of returning an int.

Comment: "numpy.random.randint seems like it would work but it will return an array" - it'll only do that if you tell it to. (Also, if you're using NumPy and you don't *want* an array, you may be using NumPy wrong.)

Comment: `action = random.randint(0,2)` totally did the trick thank you for all the fast responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use the random module and use random.randint which generates a random integer

```
import random 

number = random.randint(0,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
for i in range(5):
    action = np.random.randint(0,3)
    print(action)
```